# Trying to make an image column sortable in our DataGridView - all that's displayed is System.Drawing.Bitmap instead of the image

Tags: winforms, sorting, datagridview

Have tried following the advice in the [MSDN article: How to: Customize Data Formatting in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1cc356h.aspx) but when the form is shown all that's displayed in each cell is `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.

Must be something basic we're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved - nothing wrong with the cell formatting code in the MSDN article. But in our version our column was of type `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` when of course what's needed is a `DataGridViewImageColumn`.